# Check if all elements on a form is fully loaded C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a C# application using Visual Studio 2015
it has 2 forms, on form1 I have a button that when clicked
shows form2, now what I would like to do is print form2 
after it has fully loaded, I am using the printform control 
on form2 to do this, if I use this on the the form_load event 
it prints a blank page and then shows the form, I have 
also tried using it on form_Shown, however this prints a box 
where the elements are but not the element itself as if they have
not finished loading, there is  probably a better way to do this 
but I am new to C# so still learning

Below is an example of the code that I have on form2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form2: Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form2_Shown);
        }

        private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printForm.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check with the MSDN example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thank's @Steve I will look into it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Shown event fires a wee bit too early.  The form's frame and background is painted but the rest follows later.  Painting is a low priority task that occurs only when nothing else needs to be done, firing the Shown event happens first.

The workaround is simple, just ask the form to finish updating itself by calling its Update() method.  Fix:

```
    private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Update();
        printForm.Print();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Hans Passant, that works :) problem sorted thanks again